# compare and update a string

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am trying to find a way, how to compare two strings and upgrade the first, when the second has more in it.
For example

> ```
> String A="This is a statement!"; 
> String B="This is a statement! Good luck!"; 
> if(A<B{   //B has more letters
>         //Upgrade A }
>   else{ //Upgrade B
>       }
> ```

I mean with upgrade not overwriting like A=B.
My strings has usually much lines.
I want to keep the value of the string and just insert the new things from the other String.
Has someone an idea?

EDIT: Thank you for the nice answers.
Unfortunetly I didnt exlain it more clear, sorry my fault.
My problem is, that I do now know where the changes are, the strings could look like this:

```
String A: 
A 
B 
C//Good morning, sir 
D//A comment 
E


String B: 
A 
B//Yes 
C 
D 
DD 
E

The result should be: 
A 
B//Yes 
C//Good morning, sir 
D//A comment 
DD 
E
```

Comment: What's upgrade? Also, what happens if the strings does not share a prefix? Note that Java does not have operator overloading, and even if it has, `<` will most likely compare the lexical ordering.

Comment: This code will not compile.

Comment: Write "String length Java" and you'll be amazed from the results!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
String A="This is a statement!"; 
String B="This is a statement! Good luck!";

if (A.length() < B.length()){   //B has more letters
        A += B.subString(A.length(), B.length()-1);
} else{ 
        B += A.subString(B.length(), A.length()-1);
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for :).

Comment: Thank you. Of course this is the best solution for the problem I described by an oversight. I ll mark this as solution for sure.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if(A.length() < B.length() {   //B has more letters
    //Upgrade A 
}
else { //Upgrade B

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) to get the length of a String.

Answer (score 0):

Compare strings by length, using **String.length()**
For example

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str1 = new String("This is a statement!");
      String Str2 = new String("This is a statement! Good luck!" );

     if(Str1.length() > Str2.length())
        Str2 += Str1;
     else
        Str1 += Str2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String A = "This is a statement!"; 
String B = "This is a statement! Good luck!"; 
if (B.length() > A.length()) { //B has more letters
    //Upgrade A
} else {
    //Upgrade B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `Strings` by length:

```
if (A.length() > B.length()) {
    B = A;
} else {
    A = B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!B.contains(A)){
   A = B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (B.length() > A.length()) { // upgrade B as it's longer 
} else if (A.length() > B.length()) { // upgrade A as its longer
} else if (A.length() == B.length()) { // not sure what to do here as they're of equal length
}
```

Aside from null-checking, I believe this encompasses every possible case.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you'll use a combination of `subsString()` and `length()`. Take `b.subString(a.length, b.length-1)` and concatenate that substring to `a`

Answer (score 0):

Use String.length() to compare the size then concat the end of the longest chain.

```
String a="This is a statement!"; 
String b="This is a statement! Good luck!"; 

if(b.length() > a.length()) {
    a = a.concat(b.substring(a.length()));
}
else if(a.length() > b.length())
{
    b = b.concat(a.substring(b.length()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
if(A.contains(B) && !A.equals(B))
{
  A += B.substring(A.length(),B.length());
}
```